# Why does context.SaveChanges() update every row in the table?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I wrote some code using C# and Entity Framework 6 (EF6)
with MySql.
The IDE is Visual Studio 2019 preview.

I installed these packages:

```
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.10.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.Entity" version="6.10.8" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Inserting and Selecting are works correctly
but Updating works wired.

I put some number(something like 2 or 100) into `tbx_CarId`
and I expected that EF6 updates only ONE row,
but it updates every low in the table.

```
private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (Parking context = new Parking(connection, false))
        {
            context.Database.Log = (string message) => { Console.WriteLine(message); };

            int targetId = Int32.Parse(tbx_CarId.Text);
            var blogs = from b in context.Cars
                        where b.CarId == targetId
                        select b;
            Car item = blogs.Single();
            item.Model = tbx_NewModel.Text;
            int numOfSavedLows = context.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("numOfSavedLows: " + numOfSavedLows.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The method `context.SaveChanges()` always returns an exact number, 1,
and on the console window, "numOfSavedLows: 1" is printed.

But the every row is changed whenever I execute that method.

Also, the logger of EF6 writes on the console something like this:

```
Started transaction at 2019-01-03 오후 6:47:59 +09:00
`Car_Update`
-- CarId: '2' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- Model: 'new value of the model' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 5)
-- Year: '2013' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- Manufacturer: 'Dodge' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 5)
-- Executing at 2019-01-03 오후 6:47:59 +09:00
-- Completed in 6 ms with result: 16

Committed transaction at 2019-01-03 오후 6:47:59 +09:00
Disposed transaction at 2019-01-03 오후 6:47:59 +09:00
```

Please look at the line `-- Completed in 6 ms with result: 16`
The number(in this case, 16) is the count of every row in `Car` table.

Why does EF6 update every low?
How can I fix it?

The rest of the codes are here:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
class Parking : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public Parking()
      : base()
    {
        // constructor is empty
    }

    // Constructor to use on a DbConnection that is already opened
    public Parking(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
      : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
        // constructor is empty
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().MapToStoredProcedures();
    }
}
```

and

```
class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

Most of the codes are from here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

update 1:
The table `Cars` looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1cle.png)
(The schema and table are generated by EF6 automatically)

update 2:
The values of the rows are like this:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK8Vx.png) and 
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SUF6.png) (args are 8, 'new value')

Comment: Are you sure, that 16 rows were updated? Maybe table contains index, and it was rebuild? Have you used profiler to see generated sql code?

Comment: That can only happen when `CarId` isn't unique and there are 16 records having `CarId == 2`.

Comment: Did you check the State of the Entities in the ChangeTracker of your DbContext? All of them should equal EntityState.Unchanged, except the entity you changed.

Comment: When you run a database trace (or use https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof) to see the exact commands being sent to the database, what is being submitted?

Comment: Can you go into database and find `Car_Update` procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Context.Savechanges() finds all changes in all dbsets(entities) and commit all of them in the database, it is a draw in Entity framework.

Comment: Still, he only changed one row. The ChangeTracker of the DbContext should contain all elements, but most of them should have a State equal to EntityState.Unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your entity doesn't have a primary column defined.
That way, Entity Framework cannot select the correlating data in the table to your entity and updates every row where "everything" (every entry matches the primary key definition) meets the condition.
You need to add something like

```
[Key, Column("Car_ID_IN_DB"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int CarId{ get; set;}
```

to your modeled `Cars` table on your `CarId` (you don't show this definition)

This only works if you are using CodeFirst, if you are using DbFirst you should check the generated entity of `Cars`if it's modeled correctly and if you modeled a primary key in your DB.

Comment: But the table `Cars` has a primary key... `CarId` column is the primary key. check this out. https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1cle.png

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [official EF6 GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/564),

> Removing the MapToStoredProcedure in my DbContext fixes the issue.

I would tell you to try removing the "MapToStoredProcedures()" code and see if you get any different result.